# When and why we must use the malloc?

Tags: c++, malloc

I just want to know When and Why we must use the **malloc** and allocate sufficient memory.

Should I use in destination pointer or what?

Comment: As your question is tagged with c++, I would say you very rarely need to use `malloc`. Prefer `std::make_unique`, `std::make_shared` and sometimes `new`. Not sure if you are asking when `malloc` specifically should be preferred or if you are asking about dynamic memory allocation in general.

Comment: if you ask that question, the answer is: never

Comment: In C++? You should never call `malloc` in C++. In most situation it's simply wrong and will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: More generally, it seems to me that you could need [a good beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read.

Comment: If you know what you're doing and you decide that malloc is the right tool (e.g. inside custom allocators).  I don't see any use for it in regular C++ code.

Comment: I wonder was this the actual question (when to use malloc in c++) or was it more about when to use dynamic memory in general??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, the use of `malloc`/`free` is discouraged. You should use `new`/`delete` instead, which allocate a block of memory **AND** initialize it (default construction). Since C++11, even `new`/`delete` should be avoided and you should use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` instead. However, `malloc` might still be useful for raw buffers and memory pools, but only in large scale applications where each cycle counts. For normal cases like yours (I suppose), don't even think about it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use malloc in C++. Use `new`/`delete` or `new[]`/`delete[]` instead or use a smart pointer like `std::shared_ptr<T>()`.

`malloc` does not call an objects constructor and `malloc` must be undone with `free`, (which does not call an objects destructor). On top of that, `malloc` is not type-safe as it returns a `void*`. Unless you have good reason, stay away from `malloc`.